# How to create an angular 7 component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to create an angular 7 component?  I forked a jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gauravshrestha/fdxsywLv/ The data points on this chart can be dragged up and down .  I would like to turn this into a component and pass objects in the variable `acoptions` as input parameters. If there is an existing angular component that creates draggable line charts, it would work for my purpose as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Looking at your jsFiddle it appears you are relying on `Chart.js` for charting and `d3` helpers for events and drag-drop. The same can be done using angular libraries like `Chart.js`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts and `D3`: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I do have a stackblitz angular example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-g  .  It works fine in PC, and also in Chrome's devtools emulating iPad but I can't get the data points to drag up and down in an actual touch device.  

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have the angular CLI installed you can create a component using the command:

```
ng generate component <component-name or folder>
```

[Here is a link to the official Angular CLI documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component)

Once you have the component generated it should be relatively straight forward to drop the html, css and js code into the corresponding files.

To setup a variable as an input parameter, annotate it with `@Input() acoptions` in your component class.

[Link to angular input documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

One more note, you may want to create an interface for `acoptions` since it is a fairly complicated data object, with layers. This will also add some fidelity to your code.

Comment: `ng g component exampleComponent or ng generate component exampleComponent or // creating component with folder ng g component folderName/exampleComponent ` 
or if you use VSCODE editor you can make use Angular Generator package. then go to your project workspace, do right click on folder where you want create component/service/directive/modules . it will automatically create all necessary file